# close dropdown submenu doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a menu within a submenu with some items. When I open the menu by click and try to click on the submenu it doesn't open. I know because I set this property **[autoClose]="true"**. But if I change the property to false, ok it open correctly the submenu but if I click outside the menu it does not close. The behaviour that I want is that if I click outside the menu I want that the menu does close.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vzzmeb

The submenu is called **Roles**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onBlur method to programmatically close the menu